# Suddenly cannot read files anymore

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit

I'm developing a tiny game and at first it works super perfect. It loads sks files and sound files pretty well. But after a few minutes of testing, I start to get "Error loading sound resource" and particle effects all disappear.

I thought it might be the memory problem, however, the game only takes about 120M, and I haven't received any memory warnings yet.

So how can it manages to read files in the beginning and fails to do so a few minutes later? Is there something tricky in SpriteKit that I don't know? Such as after loading one hundred files successfully, the game cannot read any files anymore until the user shakes the iPhone twice and turns it upside down... If it's true, I will possible inform the players to do so in the game's tutorial...

So can anyone help me handle this...? Lots of thanks...

```
// The way I load background music:

let musicPath=Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Main", ofType: "mp3")
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: musicPath!)
do{
    try main=AVAudioPlayer(contentsOf: url)     
}catch{    
    return
}

// The way I load sound files:

let a = SKAction.playSoundFileNamed("Fire",waitForCompletion:false)
audioNode.run(a)


// The way I load SKS files:

let emitterPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Fire", ofType: "sks")!
let emitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObject(withFile: emitterPath) as! SKEmitterNode
self.addChild(emitter)
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing your code but if you're opening a lot of file readers you could run out of memory or make the files inaccessible until the other nodes reading from the files are gone.

Do you happen to know if you're creating new audio nodes every time they are rendered?

Apples documentation suggests that you create a single SKAction to be reused. So if you need to reuse your Fire action, I would create a singleton of it and run that single object over and over instead of allocating the new SKAction again and again.

[Source](https://developer.apple.com/reference/spritekit/skaction)

Comment: OK, I edited the question and provided my code above. How to close files..?

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood how you were loading the sprites. Updated my answer

Comment: Thanks. I'll try it, but I'm still not sure how to address the particle disappearance problem:)